# Understanding the definition of Sensitive dependence on initial conditions?

Tags: dynamical-systems, intuition, visualization, chaos-theory

I was trying to understand the rigorous definition of sensitive dependence on initial conditions which is as follows -

$f : X \mapsto X$ where $X$ is a metric space.

If there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall x \in X \forall \delta>0 $ there exists $y \in X$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$ and $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))$ for some $n > 0$.

Source - [Definition in the Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z1QygusbIEgC&pg=PA584&dq=%22sensitive+dependence+on+initial+conditions%22+metric&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji2Pajr8HbAhWEnJQKHXryCw8Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22sensitive%20dependence%20on%20initial%20conditions%22%20metric&f=false)

Linear Chaos, [Definition 1.21](https://books.google.com/books?id=UwsBihOIDkoC&pg=PA11)

A First Course in Discrete Dynamical Systems, [Definition 11.18](https://books.google.com/books?id=5LUPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA117)

An Intuitive explanation, visualization of the above rigorous definition would be very much helpful.

Comment: Your definition is incomplete (it does not mention $f$ again) and does match the definitions in any of the cited sources. Can you please fix this?